# Is there a way to combine those two lines into one?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to write those two lines as one:

```
const { page, totalPages, changePage } = this.props;
const pagination = { page, totalPages, changePage };
```

I could not find anywhere how to do it, it only makes sense that I would be able to do it in one line.

I was hoping for something like

```
const pagination = { page, totalPages, changePage } = this.props;
```

Comment: This is clearly the obvious way to do it, but I was hoping to not repeat `this.props` every time.

Comment: @MayankShukla "correct syntax" != "will work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it the way your are right now. You're abusing destructuring which is supposed to be used to take fields from an object and turn them into local variables. You're doing this and then immediately converting them back into an object.

To do this in one, step, simply make a new object and reference the fields you want from the old object.

```
const pagination = { page: this.props.page, totalPages: this.props.totalPages, changePage: this.props.changePage }
```

Comment: the `const` should take care of the `useless` variable. I just don't wont to repeat the `this.props` over and over again, and was hoping there is a simple way to extract those three properties into a separate object.

Comment: @Andreykul You can't. You're looking for syntactic sugar that doesn't exist. What I've shown you IS the simplest way.

Comment: was hoping for some sugar :(

Answer (score 0):

You can assign like this, But I don't understand the reason for assigning like this.

```
const pagination = { page, totalPages, changePage } = this.props;
```

Comment: While valid syntax, it doesn't do what you want, so **No**.

Comment: @Bergi can you please explain where it will fail, i just tried that and it is working i think, check this: https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/2kmjy6s0/

Comment: @MayankShukla https://jsfiddle.net/2kmjy6s0/1/ (the expected result would be `false, undefined, undefined, undefined`)

Comment: @Bergi ohh got it, thanks :)